# How to solve "ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset" error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I wrote the following command in CMD:

```
ssh ec2-user@01.01.001.001 -i node.pem
```

I receive this error:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset
```

I am hosting a website on my Windows Laptop using an Amazon EC2 instance.

How can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't comment your question due to my low rep to have some further details so I give this a try.

There could be a lot of reasons for this to happen:

- the IP is wrong; I suppose that the one you wrote is a fake one. If
  it's not, go to your EC2 panel to check the correct one;
- the username is wrong; on ubuntu servers you should use ssh `ubuntu@ip-address`
- the server is not reachable for some reason: bad security group
  configuration (is the port 22 open?), firewall on your
  network/computer...

You can add the flag -vvv to your ssh command to have a very verbose log of your connection so it will we easier to debug.